# I have a 64Gb Ram, 16 Core VM, calling CPLEX from Visual Studio 2015, how do I overcome memory issues?

Tags: .net, cplex

The cplex object itself is around 20GB, and I have 15 GB of RAM left before I get a

CPLEX ERROR 1001: Out Of Memory.

The console itself shows

[Cplex Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESb6Q.jpg)

After an initial search, I set the following parameters:

```
cp.SetParam(Cplex.IntParam.NodeFileInd, 2);
cp.SetParam(Cplex.IntParam.WorkMem, 10000000000);
cp.SetParam(Cplex.Param.WorkDir, "D:\\Temp");
cp.SetParam(Cplex.Param.WorkMem, 10000000000);
cp.SetParam(Cplex.BooleanParam.MemoryEmphasis, true);
cp.SetParam(Cplex.Param.Threads, 10);
```

And still get the exact same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running in a 64-bit process? Is the out-of-memory error referencing a lack of disk space and not ram? Is there enough room in your swap file? Can you get any more diagnostics than that? We don't really have a lot to work on here.

Comment: Yes, it is running as a 64-bit process. There is plenty of space on both disk space (>30GB) and RAM(>15GB). I haven't messed around with the paging file, as I assume it is scaled accordingly by Windows (hopefully)

Comment: The [WorkMem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9UKU_12.4.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/Parameters/topics/WorkMem.html) property, according to the IBM docs, is in units of Megabytes. The value you're specifying then means you're allowing a limit of 10000 Terabytes - 10 exabytes. Perhaps the limit is also used in some way to specify how much to expect to be able to use; maybe reducing the limit will make it try to use less.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Upon some further digging, I see that writing to disk is only triggered when the WorkMem is exceeded. Since I put in a very large value, it may never trigger the NodeSelInd parameter to write to disk. I will set WorkMem to some lower value (like 1024 MB) and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. I still see the same Cplex 1001: Out of Memory error.

Comment: The memory expands until all 64 GB RAM has been consumed and then immediately spits out the error. It never writes to disk, like it's supposed to.

Comment: It may be helpful if you can share the CPLEX log.  For example, you can redirect this into a text file using the `Cplex.SetOut` method.